# How to set global variable to use across multiple classes in test project

Tags: c#, xunit

I am using XUnit with WebApplicationFactory to write integration tests for my C# API Application

GetTokenControllerTest will call GetToken() to store the Auth code in AccessToken which can then be used through out the class. Setting the header value with the AUthorization, allowing me to access authoirsed end points in the controller

```
    public class TokenDTO
{
  public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}

public class GetTokenControllerTest : IClassFixture<TokenDTO> 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly TokenDTO _tokenDTO;

    public GetTokenControllerTest(TokenDTO tokenDTO)
    {
         _tokenDTO = tokenDTO;
         var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

       [Fact, TestPriority(1)]
        public async Task GetToken()
        {
                TokenRequestDto dto = new TokenRequestDto();
        dto.Email = "123@gmail.com";
        dto.Password = "123456";

                var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
                var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var GetTokenContentsResponse = await _client.PostAsync("/api/Tokens/Auth", content);

                var TokenJson = GetTokenContentsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var TokenDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenDto>(TokenJson);
        
        //Set token so can use through out class
                _tokenDTO.AccessToken = TokenDTO.AccessToken;

        }


        [Fact]
        public async Task CallAPIEndPoint1()
        {
        //re-use AccessToken
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _tokenDTO.AccessToken);
        var api1 = await _client.GetAsync("api/Car/CarNames");
    }
    [Fact]
        public async Task CallAPIEndPoint2()
        {
        //re-use AccessToken
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _tokenDTO.AccessToken);
        var api2 = await _client.GetAsync("api/Car/CarTypes");
    }
    [Fact]
        public async Task CallAPIEndPoint2()
        {
        //re-use AccessToken
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _tokenDTO.AccessToken);
        var api3 = await _client.GetAsync("api/Car/CarColour");
    }

}
```

So I could successfully call the controller functions:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost("CarNames")
    public async Task<IActionResult> CarNames()
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

This all works great my Q is how can I set **TokenDTO.AccessToken** to a global variable which can be accessed across all test classes for the duration of the testing?

Thank you for any response

Comment: You should avoid shared state when dealing with tests.  I have wasted so much time in my career chasing down stuff like this where people thought it was harmless (and it even could have been at the time) and then ended up causing issues and flaky tests because nothing was actually isolated or ended up changing the shared state inadvertently.  Good tests are self contained.

Comment: OK I see your point but if good tests are self contained but I need a TokenDTO.AccessToken for 95 out of 100 tests do you suggest calling the GetToken() at the beginning of each test and setting a temp TokenDTO.AccessToken for that particular test? or have you any suggestions how I can resolve this

Comment: https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

Comment: Thanks for reply yes Ive seen the documentation but public class EmptyStack and public clas SingleItemStack both create new instnaces with stack = new Stack.<int>();, so are you suggesting I create one call at the beginning of each class to retrieve the token and use that for only the contained class?

Answer (score 0):

You are one step in the right direction by using `IClassFixture`. Here is an example of how to create the Fixture class to get your token.

> ```
> public class TokenFixture
> {
>     public TokenFixture()
>     {
>         Token = GetToken().Result;
>     }
>
>     private async Task<string> GetToken()
>     {
>         // replace with actual token requesting logic
>         var token = await Task.FromResult("Token");
>
>         return token;
>     }
>
>     public string Token { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Then you can use it in your `GetTokenControllerTest.cs`:

```
public class ControllerTests: IClassFixture<TokenFixture>
{
    TokenFixture fixture;

    public ControllerTests(TokenFixture fixture)
    {

        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.Equal("Token", fixture.Token);
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Assert.Equal("Token", fixture.Token);
    }
}
```